# fillArc() in Java not blending color as expected

Tags: java, graphics, drawing

I'm trying to blend all the colors into a circle using arcs. 
However, the arc comes as one solid color and not a blend of color as I thought. 
Is it possible to?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(512,512);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics(); 

    int width = 100; 
    int height = 100; 

        g.drawOval(0,0,width, height);
        //yellow
        for( int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++){ 
            Color c = new Color(255/100*i,255,0);
            g.setColor(c);
            g.fillArc(0,0,width,height,95,11);
        }
```

Comment: You probably want a conical grident paint, like [this for example](http://www.jug-muenster.de/java2d-conical-gradient-paint-674/)

Answer (score 2):

```
g.fillArc(0,0,width,height,95,11);
```

You need to change the arc angle for every iteration and the arc size should be fixed at a certain value. I'm not sure what the value would be because I would expect you should iterate 360 times (in which case the size would be 1), not 100.

You can use the [HSL Color](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/05/hsl-color/) class to do this simply.

[image]

An HSL color allows you to change the "hue" of the color in degrees. So you just need a simple loop to set/paint the color in a 1 degree arc:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorWheel extends JPanel
{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        HSLColor color = new HSLColor( Color.YELLOW );

        for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
        {
            g.setColor( color.adjustHue(i) );
            g.fillArc( 25, 25, 200, 200, i, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(250, 250);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JComponent wheel = new ColorWheel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Color Wheel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane( wheel );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I used the `HSL Color` because it has a simple API to change the hue.

If you don't want to use that class then you can use `Color.getHSBColor(...)` method to get the color for each degree of change. Again the saturation and brightness would be fixed values and then you just change the hue.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    float hueDegree = 1 / 360.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
    {
        Color color = Color.getHSBColor(i * hueDegree, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        g.setColor( color );
        g.fillArc( 25, 25, 200, 200, i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the use of `HSLColor`, that's neat, but shame the colors butt up against each other at the end (yellow not blending into the red). Still, a nice approach

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Hmm, I didn't notice my image was off. I reran my code and the blending is fine. I think I might have created that image when I was (unintentionally) using an arc size greater than 1  so the RED overlapped a few degrees of color. Thanks for pointing out the problem in the image. It has been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Along time ago, I stumbled across a `ConicalGradientPaint` from [Harmonic Code](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com.au/) (there source is there somewhere, I just can't seem to find it again, but I've included my copy of it in the example).

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ColorWheel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ColorWheel();
    }

    public ColorWheel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            ConicalGradientPaint rgp = new ConicalGradientPaint(
                            true,
                            new Point(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2),
                            0.5f,
                            new float[]{0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360},
                            new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED});
            g2d.setPaint(rgp);

            int radius = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());

            int x = (getWidth() - radius) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - radius) / 2;

            g2d.fillOval(x, y, radius, radius);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public final class ConicalGradientPaint implements java.awt.Paint {

        private final java.awt.geom.Point2D CENTER;
        private final double[] FRACTION_ANGLES;
        private final double[] RED_STEP_LOOKUP;
        private final double[] GREEN_STEP_LOOKUP;
        private final double[] BLUE_STEP_LOOKUP;
        private final double[] ALPHA_STEP_LOOKUP;
        private final java.awt.Color[] COLORS;
        private static final float INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST = 1f / 255f;

        /**
         * Standard constructor which takes the FRACTIONS in values from 0.0f to
         * 1.0f
         *
         * @param CENTER
         * @param GIVEN_FRACTIONS
         * @param GIVEN_COLORS
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException
         */
        public ConicalGradientPaint(final java.awt.geom.Point2D CENTER, final float[] GIVEN_FRACTIONS, final java.awt.Color[] GIVEN_COLORS) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            this(false, CENTER, 0.0f, GIVEN_FRACTIONS, GIVEN_COLORS);
        }

        /**
         * Enhanced constructor which takes the FRACTIONS in degress from 0.0f to
         * 360.0f and also an GIVEN_OFFSET in degrees around the rotation CENTER
         *
         * @param USE_DEGREES
         * @param CENTER
         * @param GIVEN_OFFSET
         * @param GIVEN_FRACTIONS
         * @param GIVEN_COLORS
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException
         */
        public ConicalGradientPaint(final boolean USE_DEGREES, final java.awt.geom.Point2D CENTER, final float GIVEN_OFFSET, final float[] GIVEN_FRACTIONS, final java.awt.Color[] GIVEN_COLORS) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            // Check that fractions and colors are of the same size
            if (GIVEN_FRACTIONS.length != GIVEN_COLORS.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fractions and colors must be equal in size");
            }

            final java.util.ArrayList<Float> FRACTION_LIST = new java.util.ArrayList<Float>(GIVEN_FRACTIONS.length);
            final float OFFSET;
            if (USE_DEGREES) {
                final double DEG_FRACTION = 1f / 360f;
                if (Double.compare((GIVEN_OFFSET * DEG_FRACTION), -0.5) == 0) {
                    OFFSET = -0.5f;
                } else if (Double.compare((GIVEN_OFFSET * DEG_FRACTION), 0.5) == 0) {
                    OFFSET = 0.5f;
                } else {
                    OFFSET = (float) (GIVEN_OFFSET * DEG_FRACTION);
                }
                for (float fraction : GIVEN_FRACTIONS) {
                    FRACTION_LIST.add((float) (fraction * DEG_FRACTION));
                }
            } else {
                // Now it seems to work with rotation of 0.5f, below is the old code to correct the problem
//            if (GIVEN_OFFSET == -0.5)
//            {
//                // This is needed because of problems in the creation of the Raster
//                // with a angle offset of exactly -0.5
//                OFFSET = -0.49999f;
//            }
//            else if (GIVEN_OFFSET == 0.5)
//            {
//                // This is needed because of problems in the creation of the Raster
//                // with a angle offset of exactly +0.5
//                OFFSET = 0.499999f;
//            }
//            else
                {
                    OFFSET = GIVEN_OFFSET;
                }
                for (float fraction : GIVEN_FRACTIONS) {
                    FRACTION_LIST.add(fraction);
                }
            }

            // Check for valid offset
            if (OFFSET > 0.5f || OFFSET < -0.5f) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Offset has to be in the range of -0.5 to 0.5");
            }

            // Adjust fractions and colors array in the case where startvalue != 0.0f and/or endvalue != 1.0f
            final java.util.List<java.awt.Color> COLOR_LIST = new java.util.ArrayList<java.awt.Color>(GIVEN_COLORS.length);
            COLOR_LIST.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(GIVEN_COLORS));

            // Assure that fractions start with 0.0f
            if (FRACTION_LIST.get(0) != 0.0f) {
                FRACTION_LIST.add(0, 0.0f);
                final java.awt.Color TMP_COLOR = COLOR_LIST.get(0);
                COLOR_LIST.add(0, TMP_COLOR);
            }

            // Assure that fractions end with 1.0f
            if (FRACTION_LIST.get(FRACTION_LIST.size() - 1) != 1.0f) {
                FRACTION_LIST.add(1.0f);
                COLOR_LIST.add(GIVEN_COLORS[0]);
            }

            // Recalculate the fractions and colors with the given offset
            final java.util.Map<Float, java.awt.Color> FRACTION_COLORS = recalculate(FRACTION_LIST, COLOR_LIST, OFFSET);

            // Clear the original FRACTION_LIST and COLOR_LIST
            FRACTION_LIST.clear();
            COLOR_LIST.clear();

            // Sort the hashmap by fraction and add the values to the FRACION_LIST and COLOR_LIST
            final java.util.SortedSet<Float> SORTED_FRACTIONS = new java.util.TreeSet<Float>(FRACTION_COLORS.keySet());
            final java.util.Iterator<Float> ITERATOR = SORTED_FRACTIONS.iterator();
            while (ITERATOR.hasNext()) {
                final float CURRENT_FRACTION = ITERATOR.next();
                FRACTION_LIST.add(CURRENT_FRACTION);
                COLOR_LIST.add(FRACTION_COLORS.get(CURRENT_FRACTION));
            }

            // Set the values
            this.CENTER = CENTER;
            COLORS = COLOR_LIST.toArray(new java.awt.Color[]{});

            // Prepare lookup table for the angles of each fraction
            final int MAX_FRACTIONS = FRACTION_LIST.size();
            this.FRACTION_ANGLES = new double[MAX_FRACTIONS];
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FRACTIONS; i++) {
                FRACTION_ANGLES[i] = FRACTION_LIST.get(i) * 360;
            }

            // Prepare lookup tables for the color stepsize of each color
            RED_STEP_LOOKUP = new double[COLORS.length];
            GREEN_STEP_LOOKUP = new double[COLORS.length];
            BLUE_STEP_LOOKUP = new double[COLORS.length];
            ALPHA_STEP_LOOKUP = new double[COLORS.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < (COLORS.length - 1); i++) {
                RED_STEP_LOOKUP[i] = ((COLORS[i + 1].getRed() - COLORS[i].getRed()) * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST) / (FRACTION_ANGLES[i + 1] - FRACTION_ANGLES[i]);
                GREEN_STEP_LOOKUP[i] = ((COLORS[i + 1].getGreen() - COLORS[i].getGreen()) * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST) / (FRACTION_ANGLES[i + 1] - FRACTION_ANGLES[i]);
                BLUE_STEP_LOOKUP[i] = ((COLORS[i + 1].getBlue() - COLORS[i].getBlue()) * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST) / (FRACTION_ANGLES[i + 1] - FRACTION_ANGLES[i]);
                ALPHA_STEP_LOOKUP[i] = ((COLORS[i + 1].getAlpha() - COLORS[i].getAlpha()) * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST) / (FRACTION_ANGLES[i + 1] - FRACTION_ANGLES[i]);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Recalculates the fractions in the FRACTION_LIST and their associated
         * colors in the COLOR_LIST with a given OFFSET. Because the conical
         * gradients always starts with 0 at the top and clockwise direction you
         * could rotate the defined conical gradient from -180 to 180 degrees which
         * equals values from -0.5 to +0.5
         *
         * @param FRACTION_LIST
         * @param COLOR_LIST
         * @param OFFSET
         * @return Hashmap that contains the recalculated fractions and colors after
         * a given rotation
         */
        private java.util.HashMap<Float, java.awt.Color> recalculate(final java.util.List<Float> FRACTION_LIST, final java.util.List<java.awt.Color> COLOR_LIST, final float OFFSET) {
            // Recalculate the fractions and colors with the given offset
            final int MAX_FRACTIONS = FRACTION_LIST.size();
            final java.util.HashMap<Float, java.awt.Color> FRACTION_COLORS = new java.util.HashMap<Float, java.awt.Color>(MAX_FRACTIONS);
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FRACTIONS; i++) {
                // Add offset to fraction
                final float TMP_FRACTION = FRACTION_LIST.get(i) + OFFSET;

                // Color related to current fraction
                final java.awt.Color TMP_COLOR = COLOR_LIST.get(i);

                // Check each fraction for limits (0...1)
                if (TMP_FRACTION <= 0) {
                    FRACTION_COLORS.put(1.0f + TMP_FRACTION + 0.0001f, TMP_COLOR);

                    final float NEXT_FRACTION;
                    final java.awt.Color NEXT_COLOR;
                    if (i < MAX_FRACTIONS - 1) {
                        NEXT_FRACTION = FRACTION_LIST.get(i + 1) + OFFSET;
                        NEXT_COLOR = COLOR_LIST.get(i + 1);
                    } else {
                        NEXT_FRACTION = 1 - FRACTION_LIST.get(0) + OFFSET;
                        NEXT_COLOR = COLOR_LIST.get(0);
                    }
                    if (NEXT_FRACTION > 0) {
                        final java.awt.Color NEW_FRACTION_COLOR = getColorFromFraction(TMP_COLOR, NEXT_COLOR, (int) ((NEXT_FRACTION - TMP_FRACTION) * 10000), (int) ((-TMP_FRACTION) * 10000));
                        FRACTION_COLORS.put(0.0f, NEW_FRACTION_COLOR);
                        FRACTION_COLORS.put(1.0f, NEW_FRACTION_COLOR);
                    }
                } else if (TMP_FRACTION >= 1) {
                    FRACTION_COLORS.put(TMP_FRACTION - 1.0f - 0.0001f, TMP_COLOR);

                    final float PREVIOUS_FRACTION;
                    final java.awt.Color PREVIOUS_COLOR;
                    if (i > 0) {
                        PREVIOUS_FRACTION = FRACTION_LIST.get(i - 1) + OFFSET;
                        PREVIOUS_COLOR = COLOR_LIST.get(i - 1);
                    } else {
                        PREVIOUS_FRACTION = FRACTION_LIST.get(MAX_FRACTIONS - 1) + OFFSET;
                        PREVIOUS_COLOR = COLOR_LIST.get(MAX_FRACTIONS - 1);
                    }
                    if (PREVIOUS_FRACTION < 1) {
                        final java.awt.Color NEW_FRACTION_COLOR = getColorFromFraction(TMP_COLOR, PREVIOUS_COLOR, (int) ((TMP_FRACTION - PREVIOUS_FRACTION) * 10000), (int) (TMP_FRACTION - 1.0f) * 10000);
                        FRACTION_COLORS.put(1.0f, NEW_FRACTION_COLOR);
                        FRACTION_COLORS.put(0.0f, NEW_FRACTION_COLOR);
                    }
                } else {
                    FRACTION_COLORS.put(TMP_FRACTION, TMP_COLOR);
                }
            }

            // Clear the original FRACTION_LIST and COLOR_LIST
            FRACTION_LIST.clear();
            COLOR_LIST.clear();

            return FRACTION_COLORS;
        }

        /**
         * With the START_COLOR at the beginning and the DESTINATION_COLOR at the
         * end of the given RANGE the method will calculate and return the color
         * that equals the given VALUE. e.g. a START_COLOR of BLACK (R:0, G:0, B:0,
         * A:255) and a DESTINATION_COLOR of WHITE(R:255, G:255, B:255, A:255) with
         * a given RANGE of 100 and a given VALUE of 50 will return the color that
         * is exactly in the middle of the gradient between black and white which is
         * gray(R:128, G:128, B:128, A:255) So this method is really useful to
         * calculate colors in gradients between two given colors.
         *
         * @param START_COLOR
         * @param DESTINATION_COLOR
         * @param RANGE
         * @param VALUE
         * @return Color calculated from a range of values by given value
         */
        public java.awt.Color getColorFromFraction(final java.awt.Color START_COLOR, final java.awt.Color DESTINATION_COLOR, final int RANGE, final int VALUE) {
            final float SOURCE_RED = START_COLOR.getRed() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST;
            final float SOURCE_GREEN = START_COLOR.getGreen() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST;
            final float SOURCE_BLUE = START_COLOR.getBlue() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST;
            final float SOURCE_ALPHA = START_COLOR.getAlpha() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST;

            final float DESTINATION_RED = DESTINATION_COLOR.getRed() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST;
            final float DESTINATION_GREEN = DESTINATION_COLOR.getGreen() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST;
            final float DESTINATION_BLUE = DESTINATION_COLOR.getBlue() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST;
            final float DESTINATION_ALPHA = DESTINATION_COLOR.getAlpha() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST;

            final float RED_DELTA = DESTINATION_RED - SOURCE_RED;
            final float GREEN_DELTA = DESTINATION_GREEN - SOURCE_GREEN;
            final float BLUE_DELTA = DESTINATION_BLUE - SOURCE_BLUE;
            final float ALPHA_DELTA = DESTINATION_ALPHA - SOURCE_ALPHA;

            final float RED_FRACTION = RED_DELTA / RANGE;
            final float GREEN_FRACTION = GREEN_DELTA / RANGE;
            final float BLUE_FRACTION = BLUE_DELTA / RANGE;
            final float ALPHA_FRACTION = ALPHA_DELTA / RANGE;
            //System.out.println(DISTANCE + "     " + CURRENT_FRACTION);

            return new java.awt.Color(SOURCE_RED + RED_FRACTION * VALUE, SOURCE_GREEN + GREEN_FRACTION * VALUE, SOURCE_BLUE + BLUE_FRACTION * VALUE, SOURCE_ALPHA + ALPHA_FRACTION * VALUE);
        }

        @Override
        public java.awt.PaintContext createContext(final java.awt.image.ColorModel COLOR_MODEL, final java.awt.Rectangle DEVICE_BOUNDS, final java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D USER_BOUNDS, final java.awt.geom.AffineTransform TRANSFORM, final java.awt.RenderingHints HINTS) {
            final java.awt.geom.Point2D TRANSFORMED_CENTER = TRANSFORM.transform(CENTER, null);
            return new ConicalGradientPaintContext(TRANSFORMED_CENTER);
        }

        @Override
        public int getTransparency() {
            return java.awt.Transparency.TRANSLUCENT;
        }

        private final class ConicalGradientPaintContext implements java.awt.PaintContext {

            final private java.awt.geom.Point2D CENTER;

            public ConicalGradientPaintContext(final java.awt.geom.Point2D CENTER) {
                this.CENTER = new java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double(CENTER.getX(), CENTER.getY());
            }

            @Override
            public void dispose() {
            }

            @Override
            public java.awt.image.ColorModel getColorModel() {
                return java.awt.image.ColorModel.getRGBdefault();
            }

            @Override
            public java.awt.image.Raster getRaster(final int X, final int Y, final int TILE_WIDTH, final int TILE_HEIGHT) {
                final double ROTATION_CENTER_X = -X + CENTER.getX();
                final double ROTATION_CENTER_Y = -Y + CENTER.getY();

                final int MAX = FRACTION_ANGLES.length;

                // Create raster for given colormodel
                final java.awt.image.WritableRaster RASTER = getColorModel().createCompatibleWritableRaster(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT);

                // Create data array with place for red, green, blue and alpha values
                int[] data = new int[(TILE_WIDTH * TILE_HEIGHT * 4)];

                double dx;
                double dy;
                double distance;
                double angle;
                double currentRed = 0;
                double currentGreen = 0;
                double currentBlue = 0;
                double currentAlpha = 0;

                for (int py = 0; py < TILE_HEIGHT; py++) {
                    for (int px = 0; px < TILE_WIDTH; px++) {

                        // Calculate the distance between the current position and the rotation angle
                        dx = px - ROTATION_CENTER_X;
                        dy = py - ROTATION_CENTER_Y;
                        distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

                        // Avoid division by zero
                        if (distance == 0) {
                            distance = 1;
                        }

                        // 0 degree on top
                        angle = Math.abs(Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(dx / distance)));

                        if (dx >= 0 && dy <= 0) {
                            angle = 90.0 - angle;
                        } else if (dx >= 0 && dy >= 0) {
                            angle += 90.0;
                        } else if (dx <= 0 && dy >= 0) {
                            angle += 90.0;
                        } else if (dx <= 0 && dy <= 0) {
                            angle = 450.0 - angle;
                        }

                        // Check for each angle in fractionAngles array
                        for (int i = 0; i < (MAX - 1); i++) {
                            if ((angle >= FRACTION_ANGLES[i])) {
                                currentRed = COLORS[i].getRed() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST + (angle - FRACTION_ANGLES[i]) * RED_STEP_LOOKUP[i];
                                currentGreen = COLORS[i].getGreen() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST + (angle - FRACTION_ANGLES[i]) * GREEN_STEP_LOOKUP[i];
                                currentBlue = COLORS[i].getBlue() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST + (angle - FRACTION_ANGLES[i]) * BLUE_STEP_LOOKUP[i];
                                currentAlpha = COLORS[i].getAlpha() * INT_TO_FLOAT_CONST + (angle - FRACTION_ANGLES[i]) * ALPHA_STEP_LOOKUP[i];
                                continue;
                            }
                        }

                        // Fill data array with calculated color values
                        final int BASE = (py * TILE_WIDTH + px) * 4;
                        data[BASE + 0] = (int) (currentRed * 255);
                        data[BASE + 1] = (int) (currentGreen * 255);
                        data[BASE + 2] = (int) (currentBlue * 255);
                        data[BASE + 3] = (int) (currentAlpha * 255);
                    }
                }

                // Fill the raster with the data
                RASTER.setPixels(0, 0, TILE_WIDTH, TILE_HEIGHT, data);

                return RASTER;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To try and do what you're doing with a pie slices, you need to slow alter the color from one point to another, using very small slices.  So, while you might start with `Color.RED` and want to blend to `Color.YELLOW`, you would actually need to generate each color between them (based on the distance)

For example...

[image: ColorBlend]

```
import core.ui.ColorUtilities;
import static core.ui.ColorUtilities.blend;
import static core.ui.ColorUtilities.getFractionIndicies;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ColorWheel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ColorWheel();
    }

    public ColorWheel() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            float fractions[] = new float[]{0, 0.16f, 0.33f, 0.5f, 0.66f, 0.83f, 1f};
            Color colors[] = new Color[]{Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.CYAN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.RED};
            for (int index = 0; index < getWidth(); index++) {

                float progress = (float) index / getWidth();
                System.out.println(progress);
                Color color = blendColors(fractions, colors, progress);
                g2d.setColor(color);
                g2d.drawLine(index, 0, index, getHeight());
            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    /**
     * This will attempt to blend two colors that site between the supplied
     * progress value, based on the distance of the progress value...
     *
     * For example, if you have a series of fractions of {0f, 0.5f, 1f} and a
     * progress of 25%, the resulting color will be a 50% blend of the first and
     * second color (as the progress is half between those two points)
     *
     * @param fractions
     * @param colors
     * @param progress
     * @return
     */
    public static Color blendColors(float[] fractions, Color[] colors, float progress) {

        Color color = null;

        if (fractions != null) {

            if (colors != null) {

                if (fractions.length == colors.length) {

                    int[] indicies = getFractionIndicies(fractions, progress);

                    float[] range = new float[]{fractions[indicies[0]], fractions[indicies[1]]};
                    Color[] colorRange = new Color[]{colors[indicies[0]], colors[indicies[1]]};

                    float max = range[1] - range[0];
                    float value = progress - range[0];
                    float weight = value / max;

                    color = blend(colorRange[0], colorRange[1], 1f - weight);

                } else {

                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fractions and colours must have equal number of elements");

                }

            } else {

                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Colours can't be null");

            }

        } else {

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Fractions can't be null");

        }

        return color;

    }
}
```

I know, it's note a wheel, but i was demonstrating the blending algorithm, I'll leave the pie slicing up to you ;)

Just proving to myself it could work...

[image: Color Wheel]

```
int dimeter = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
int x = (getWidth() - dimeter) / 2;
int y = (getHeight() - dimeter) / 2;

for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle++) {

    float progress = (float) angle / 360;
    System.out.println(progress);
    Color color = blendColors(fractions, colors, progress);
    g2d.setColor(color);
    g2d.fillArc(x, y, dimeter, dimeter, angle + 90, 2);

}
```